# Java 8 Stream Mapping Grouping operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have following two classes:

`Person`:

```
public class Person {

    private final Long id;
    private final String address;
    private final String phone;

    public Person(Long id, String address, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", address=" + address + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
    }
}
```

`CollectivePerson`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CollectivePerson {

    private final Long id;
    private final Set<String> addresses;
    private final Set<String> phones;

    public CollectivePerson(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.addresses = new HashSet<>();
        this.phones = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<String> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public Set<String> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CollectivePerson [id=" + id + ", addresses=" + addresses + ", phones=" + phones + "]";
    }
}
```

I would like to have stream operation so that:

- The `Person` mapped into `CollectivePerson`
- The `address` and `phone` of `Person` merged into `addresses` and `phones` respectively in `CollectivePerson` for all the `Person`s having same `id`

I have written the following piece of code for this purpose:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person(1L, "Address 1", "Phone 1");
        Person person2 = new Person(2L, "Address 2", "Phone 2");
        Person person3 = new Person(3L, "Address 3", "Phone 3");
        Person person11 = new Person(1L, "Address 4", "Phone 4");
        Person person21 = new Person(2L, "Address 5", "Phone 5");
        Person person22 = new Person(2L, "Address 6", "Phone 6");

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(person1);
        persons.add(person11);
        persons.add(person2);
        persons.add(person21);
        persons.add(person22);
        persons.add(person3);

        Map<Long, CollectivePerson> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<CollectivePerson> collectivePersons = persons.stream()
                .map((Person person) -> {
                    CollectivePerson collectivePerson = map.get(person.getId());

                    if (Objects.isNull(collectivePerson)) {
                        collectivePerson = new CollectivePerson(person.getId());
                        map.put(person.getId(), collectivePerson);

                        collectivePerson.getAddresses().add(person.getAddress());
                        collectivePerson.getPhones().add(person.getPhone());

                        return collectivePerson;
                    } else {
                        collectivePerson.getAddresses().add(person.getAddress());
                        collectivePerson.getPhones().add(person.getPhone());

                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.<CollectivePerson>toList());

        collectivePersons.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

It does the job and outputs as:

```
CollectivePerson [id=1, addresses=[Address 1, Address 4], phones=[Phone 1, Phone 4]]
CollectivePerson [id=2, addresses=[Address 2, Address 6, Address 5], phones=[Phone 5, Phone 2, Phone 6]]
CollectivePerson [id=3, addresses=[Address 3], phones=[Phone 3]]
```

But I believe there could be a better way, stream way of grouping to achieve the same. Any pointer would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manipulating an external `Map`, you should use a collector. There are `toMap` and `groupingBy`, both allowing to solve the problem, though a bit verbose due to your class design. The main obstacle is the lack of an existing method to either, merge a `Person` into a `CollectivePerson` or construct a `CollectivePerson` from a given `Person` instance, or a method for merging two `CollectivePerson` instances.

One way to do it using built-in collectors would be

```
List<CollectivePerson> collectivePersons = persons.stream()
    .map(p -> {
        CollectivePerson cp = new CollectivePerson(p.getId());
        cp.getAddresses().add(p.getAddress());
        cp.getPhones().add(p.getPhone());
        return cp;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(
        CollectivePerson::getId, Function.identity(),
        (cp1, cp2) -> {
            cp1.getAddresses().addAll(cp2.getAddresses());
            cp1.getPhones().addAll(cp2.getPhones());
            return cp1;
        }),
      m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())
    ));
```

but in this case, a custom collector might be simpler:

```
Collection<CollectivePerson> collectivePersons = persons.stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap<Long,CollectivePerson>::new,
        (m,p) -> {
            CollectivePerson cp=m.computeIfAbsent(p.getId(), CollectivePerson::new);
            cp.getAddresses().add(p.getAddress());
            cp.getPhones().add(p.getPhone());
        },
        (m1,m2) -> m2.forEach((l,cp) -> m1.merge(l, cp, (cp1,cp2) -> {
            cp1.getAddresses().addAll(cp2.getAddresses());
            cp1.getPhones().addAll(cp2.getPhones());
            return cp1;
        }))).values();
```

Both would benefit from a predefined method to merge two `CollectivePerson` instances, whereas the first variant would also benefit from a `CollectivePerson(Long id, Set<String> addresses, Set<String> phones)` constructor or even better, a `CollectivePerson(Person p)` constructor while the second would benefit from an `CollectivePerson.add(Person p)` method…

Note that the second variant returns the `Collection` view of the `Map`s values without copying. If you really need a `List`, you can contract it as easy as using `new ArrayList<>( «map» .values())` like the first variant does in the finisher function.

Comment: Thank you, I have taken your second variant and it is very fast. Operated on ~10000000 `Person`s within ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` with a merge function:

```
public static <T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>>
Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                            Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                            BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                            Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

The mapping looks like this:

```
Map<Long,CollectivePerson> collectivePersons =
  persons.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap (Person::getId,
                                    p -> {
                                      CollectivePerson cp = new CollectivePerson (p.getId());
                                      cp.getAddresses().add (p.getAddress());
                                      cp.getPhones().add(p.getPhone());
                                      return cp;
                                    },
                                    (cp1,cp2) -> {
                                      cp1.getAddresses().addAll(cp2.getAddresses());
                                      cp1.getPhones().addAll(cp2.getPhones());
                                      return cp1;
                                    },
                                    HashMap::new));
```

You can easily extract the `List<CollectivePerson>` from that `Map` using:

```
new ArrayList<>(collectivePersons.values())
```

Here's the output `Map` for your sample input:

```
{1=CollectivePerson [id=1, addresses=[Address 1, Address 4], phones=[Phone 1, Phone 4]], 
 2=CollectivePerson [id=2, addresses=[Address 2, Address 6, Address 5], phones=[Phone 5, Phone 2, Phone 6]], 
 3=CollectivePerson [id=3, addresses=[Address 3], phones=[Phone 3]]}
```

Comment: There is no need to specify `HashMap::new`; this task doesn’t require the map to be an instance of `HashMap`…

Comment: @Holger You are right. For some reason I thought that the only variant of `toMap` that takes a merge function also required a Supplier. That said, I just noticed that the implementation of the 3 argument toMap (i.e. without a Supplier) is `return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, HashMap::new);` :)

Comment: Yeah, in the current implementation, it always produces a `HashMap`, just as `toList()` always produces an `ArrayList`, however, this is not guaranteed and if there is no requirement to get an exact instance of these types, you should allow the implementation to change for whatever benefit the change promises. And it’s the other way round, there is no method taking a map supplier without requiring a merge function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `groupBy` collector to group your people!

```
List<CollectivePerson> list = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId)).entrySet().stream().map(x -> {
    // map all the addresses from the list of persons sharing the same id
    Set<String> addresses = x.getValue().stream().map(Person::getAddress).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    // map all the phones from the list of persons sharing the same id
    Set<String> phones = x.getValue().stream().map(Person::getPhone).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    // declare this constructor that takes three parameters
    return new CollectivePerson(x.getKey(), addresses, phones);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For this to work you need to add this constructor:

```
public CollectivePerson(Long id, Set<String> addresses, Set<String> phones) {
    this.id = id;
    this.addresses = addresses;
    this.phones = phones;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Long, CollectivePerson> map = persons.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                            Main::downColl)));
```

---

Using a method reference for creating the `CollectivePerson` object from the list of Persons which have the same `id`.

```
public static CollectivePerson downColl(List<Person> ps) {

    CollectivePerson cp = new CollectivePerson(ps.get(0).getId());          
    for (Person p:ps) {
        cp.getAddresses().add(p.getAddress());
        cp.getPhones().add(p.getPhone());
    }
    return cp;
}
```